# 2-way ANOVA (aov) produces no F or P values

Tags: r, anova, p-value

I have data that has been subjected to one of two treatments (solution added or not) and is in a random block design. I have 8 blocks (numbered 1-8) but in the aov, df=1. R didn't recognise there were 8, so I lettered them (B1, B2 etc). Now there is no F value or p value in the two-way aov, although now the df=7.

Originally:

```
soilaov <- aov(Si.arc.leaf~Block*Treatment, data=soilbd)
summary(soilaov)
```

Output

```
                `Df`    `Sum Sq`   `Mean Sq` `F value` `Pr(>F)`

Block            `1` `5.174e-05` `5.174e-05`   `3.941` `0.0705 .`

Treatment        `1` `2.526e-05` `2.526e-05`   `1.924` `0.1907`  
Block:Treatment  `1` `7.310e-06` `7.310e-06`   `0.557` `0.4699`  
Residuals       `12` `1.576e-04` `1.313e-05`
```

Now:

```
soilaov <- aov(Si.arc.leaf~Block*Treatment, data=soilbd)
summary(soilaov)
```

Output

```
                `Df`    `Sum Sq`   `Mean Sq`
Block            `7` `1.647e-04` `2.352e-05`

Treatment        `1` `2.526e-05` `2.526e-05`

Block:Treatment  `7` `5.193e-05` `7.419e-06`
```

Comment: `?summary.aov` says that the additional columns will only be provided if there are residual degrees of freedom - from your original output (when you where regressing on a numerical _Treatment_) you had residual degrees of freedom, but summing them makes it seem you have no replication in your design with which to estimate standard errors once you have taken the interaction into account.

Comment: for this design I think it would be appropriate to leave out the block by treatment interaction, i.e. use `Block+Treatment`, because R will then use the interaction mean square (i.e. the `Block:Treatment`) term as the residual variance/error term.  If you generate the ANOVA table from that model, I think you should get the appropriate F statistics for Block and Treatment (e.g. approx 3.39=2.42e-5/7.42e-6 for Treatment)

Comment: I've just tried it with Block+Treatment and it works! Thanks for replying so quickly Gavin and Ben.
Erin